# Function pointer IAR ( typedef void )

Tags: c, compiler-errors, iar

I am working on STM8S with IAR Workbench.

My code

```
typedef     void    (*MyFunction)();
```

and I got these errors:

> Error[Pe513]: a value of type "void (*)(u8)" cannot be assigned to an
>   entity of type "MyFunction"

I search on the web and I find a sample for AVR that I show below:

```
typedef void (*MyFunction)(void);
```

It also doesn't work.

Any idea for fix it.

Comment: Since the problem is in an assignment to a function pointer, you need to show something like that to produce a [mcve]. And don't neglect that `u8` type in the error.

Comment: Are you perhaps compiling as C++?

Comment: There exists no case in C where you should use an empty parameter list `()`. Particularly not when dealing with function pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For pointers to be assignable they need to point to compatible types (and the type pointed to by the left-hand side needs to have all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right-hand side). See [6.5.16.1p1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16.1p1).

Assuming `u8` is `uint8_t` AKA `unsigned char`, `void ()` is NOT compatible with `void (u8)`.

[6.7.6.3p15](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p15) (with emphasis):

> For two function types to be compatible, both shall specify compatible
>   return types.146) Moreover, the parameter type lists, if both are
>   present, shall agree in the number of parameters and in use of the
>   ellipsis terminator; corresponding parameters shall have compatible
>   types. **If one type has a parameter type list and the other type is
>   specified by a function declarator that is not part of a function
>   definition and that contains an empty identifier list, the parameter
>   list shall not have an ellipsis terminator and the type of each
>   parameter shall be compatible with the type that results from the
>   application of the default argument promotions.** If one type has a
>   parameter type list and the other type is specified by a function
>   definition that contains a (possibly empty) identifier list, both
>   shall agree in the number of parameters, and the type of each
>   prototype parameter shall be compatible with the type that results
>   from the application of the default argument promotions to the type of
>   the corresponding identifier. (In the determination of type
>   compatibility and of a composite type, each parameter declared with
>   function or array type is taken as having the adjusted type and each
>   parameter declared with qualified type is taken as having the
>   unqualified version of its declared type.)

The incompatibility is because of the promotions part. Character types get promoted to `int` so while you could do:

```
(void(*)()){0}=(void(*)(int)){0};
(void(*)(int)){0}=(void(*)()){0};
```

doing the same with u8 / `unsigned char` is not permissible:

```
(void(*)()){0}=(void(*)(unsigned char)){0}; //error
(void(*)(unsigned char)){0}=(void(*)()){0}; //error
```

You need to make the `typedef` be exactly to `void (*)(u8)` or you need to change the target function's signature to `void (int)`  (or `void (unsigned)`) or you need to cast the function pointer. (Note that function pointers are freely inter-castable but you need to cast to the proper type before calling the function).

Comment: Actually, it seems to have solved this problem, but I will work target function on more. İf it cause a new problem, I will write again.